# Not able to run Notifications Subscriber Sample of WSO2 greg

Tags: registry, wso2, wso2-bam

I am trying to run the Notifications Subscriber Sample of WSO2 Governance registry but server is not getting started its continously giving warinings:

> [2013-09-17 17:41:29,826]  INFO
>   {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.internal.HumanTaskServiceComponent} - 
>   Registering Axis2ConfigurationContextObserver [2013-09-17
>   17:42:25,774]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} - 
>   Carbon initialization is delayed due to the following unsatisfied
>   items: [2013-09-17 17:42:25,775]  WARN
>   {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} -  Waiting for
>   required OSGiAxis2Service:
>   org.wso2.carbon.registry.samples.handler-4.5.3.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: There is due to an OSGi dependency problem. Some bundles have not been successfully started due to some reason. Start the REG with the OSGi console & see what states the bundles are in.

Comment: Thanks for your response Ragavan. Please suggest how I can do that or share any link or blog that helps me on that?, as I am new to WSO2 and I don't have any idea to do that

Comment: Hi Ragavan thanks for replying, I followed these links but server is not getting up due to warning as I mentioned in description